# How to generate a range of numbers in PHP with increment of 0.25?

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to generate a list of numbers with a `0.25` difference between them, e.g

```
0
0.25
0.50
0.75
1
1.25
.....
9.75
10
```

How can this be done?

Comment: If you're using PHP 4.x, specifically which version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a [for()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop.

```
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i+=0.25)
    echo $i,'<br />';
```

Comment: Or you could : for($i=0;$i<=10/0.25;$i++) {echo $i*0.25;}

Comment: Yes, tested in 5.x, but I'm guessing it will work in earlier versions.

Comment: I've also tested this in PHP 5, if someone could test in 4 that'd be appreciated

Answer (score 14):

Use the [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function. You can specify a step (0.25):

```
$numbers = range(0, 10, 0.25);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
  echo "$number\n";
}
```

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: Wrong parameter count for range()

Comment: @Click Upvote: it seems as though the third parameter was added in PHP5 so you may be getting that message from PHP4. If that's the case, though, well... I'd argue you need to upgrade :)

Comment: I don't think so, you can supply additional arguments and you don't get warnings, but if you /miss/ any arguments you then get a warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
$numbers = range(0, 10*4);
$l = count($numbers);    
for($i=0; $i<$l;$i++){
    $numbers[$i]/=4;
}
```